# How can I maintain a variable via closure with define_method?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a macro "has_accessor_for", that accepts a symbol which is used as a parameter for an internal object that it uses (the Accessorizer object).  The problem I am having is, when multiple modules do the has_accessors_for, the parameter (scope) ends up being stuck on the last value it was assigned to.

I added a puts prior to the define_method, which shows that it's scope1, and then scope2...  But inside the define_method, it's scope2 always.  I am looking for a way to basically encapsulate that variable, so that when it the first module calls has_accessor_for, anytime my_wut is called, it will be bound to scope1... and anytime my_bleah is called, it will be bound to scope2.  But as I said, right now, both my_bleah and my_wut are bound to scope2--  If I change the order of the includes in MyModel, then they will both be bound to scope1.

```
class Accessorizer
  def initialize(record, scope)
    @record = record
    @scope = scope
  end

  def value_for(key)
    @record.send key
  end
end


module Magic
  def has_accessors_for(scope)
    accessors = {}

    puts "initial: #{scope}"
    define_method :get_value_for do |key|
      puts "inside method #{scope}"
      accessor.value_for key
    end

    define_method :accessor do
      accessors[:scope] ||= Accessorizer.new(self, scope)
    end
  end
end

module SomeAccessor
  extend Magic
  has_accessors_for :scope1

  def my_wut
    get_value_for :wut
  end
end

module SomeOtherAccessor
  extend Magic
  has_accessors_for :scope2

  def my_bleah
    get_value_for :bleah
  end
end


class MyModel
  include SomeAccessor
  include SomeOtherAccessor
  attr_accessor :wut, :bleah
end

m = MyModel.new
m.wut = 'wut'
m.bleah = 'bleah'
m.my_bleah
m.my_wut
```

#### output:

```
initial: scope1
initial: scope2
inside method scope2
inside method scope2
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the problem is not with the closures.

Long answer:

```
define_method :get_value_for do |key|
  puts "inside method #{scope}"
  accessor.value_for key
end
```

On a given class there can only be one method called `get_value_for` - the second definition will overwrite the first.

It doesn't matter so much because you're call `accessor` in both cases, however that method suffers from the same problem - you define it twice and so the second definition overwrites the first and you end up with only one `Accessorizer` object.

I think you'll need to rethink your design here.